# Python. If value on column 1 (row X) = value from column 2 (row Y), print row Y of column 3

Tags: csv, dictionary, rows

I have a .csv file, df, with 3 columns (C1, C2 and C3). All columns are of the same length (aprox. 600000 rows) and have unique values. Values in C1, which represent SNPs (single nucleotide polymorphisms) are ordered according to their location on chromosomes. C2 has the same values as C1 but they are disordered. Values in C2 are coupled to corresponding values (chromosome locations) in the same row on C3. What I want to do is to couple the chromosomal locations on C3 to the values in C1 keeping the column order of C1. In other words, generate another column with chromosome locations for the ordered SNPs on C1. So far, I tried to create a dictionary with keys from C2 and values from C3 and then using a for loop to match values on C1 and print the ordered chromosome positions, but I get C3. I understand why I get that but I don't manage to get what I want.

Any suggestion/help would be welcome. I am new into programming.

```
import csv

from collections import OrderedDict # to save keys order

import sys
sys.stdout = open("output1.csv", "w")

# C1= rows[0], C2= rows[1], C3= rows[2]
with open('df1.csv', 'rU') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    next(reader) #skip header
    d = OrderedDict((rows[1], rows[2]) for rows in reader)

for rows in reader:
    if rows[0] in d:
        print rows[2]
```

Input example:

```
C1            C2          C3
12082473    2980300     785989
11240776    4245756     799463
2980300     12082473    740857
2905036     2341354     918573
4245756     3748597     888659
3748597     11240776    765269
2341354     2905036     792480
2465126     2465126     947034
```

Desired output:

```
   C1         C4
12082473    740857
11240776    765269
2980300     785989
2905036     792480
4245756     799463
3748597     888659
2341354     918573
2465126     947034
```

Comment: Can you give a basic example of the two files?

Comment: @dawg I just edited my post, which includes the header of the 2 data files

Comment: What do you mean by 'it is not working'? There are no overlapping values of SNP in the example.

Comment: @dawg it returns me an error: "ValueError: I/O operation on closed file".

Yes there are (2980300). The files have aprox. 700000 rows and I know there are aprox. 580000 matches.

Comment: Your error is from using a generator with df1.csv

Comment: You need example data and desired output to increase the chance of a helpful response

Comment: This is really morphing into a different question.

Answer (score 1):

I am not entirely sure I understand what you are trying to do.

I think your error is from using the generator expression `d = OrderedDict((rows[0], rows[3]) for rows in reader1)` and then referring to it after the file has been closed at the end of the `with` block.

You might try something along these lines:

```
import csv
from collections import OrderedDict

d=OrderedDict()
with open('df1.csv', 'rU') as csv1, open('df2.csv', 'rU') as csv2:
    reader1 = csv.reader(csv1, delimiter=',')
    reader2 = csv.reader(csv2, delimiter=',')
    next(reader1) #skip header
    next(reader2) #skip header
    for row in reader1:
        d[row[0]]=row[3]
 #   d = OrderedDict(("a", "b") for rows in reader1)
    for row in reader2:
        if row[0] in d:
            print d[row[0]]
```

I do not see any reason you *need* an OrderedDict since this is just a mapping between `row[0]` and `row[3]` as written. You are not using the order currently.

Comment: Hi @dawg, thanks very much for your reply. I edited my question and simplified it to make it as clearer as posible. I hope you understand this time. I apologize for the inconvenience.

Comment: Hi @dawg, I just added an input example and the desired output. Many thanks